# Automatically repeat: open url and close url from list

Tags: java, javascript, php, batch-file

Is there a way to have a list of urls and do the following steps:

1. Open url
2. Load the whole page completely
3. Close the tab/page
4. Repeat

Is this possible with Java/php or a bat-file? Have somebody an example of such an script?

Comment: What's wrong with using a for/while loop?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Yes. Are you trying to achieve a webpage "hit" or something like that? What is your goal? Only full load and then close?

Comment: My goal is to use this for preloading a website from my server. I have a wordpress website with the WP Fastest cache plugin that make a cached version (.html) of a page that is visited. My website has only many pages (like 7000). So preloading after a big change could be very handy (otherwise the page is slower then normal when users have to build up the cache) Changing the wordpress-plugin is not an option, I had wp_supercache (build in page refresh) but destroyed my website 3 times. If i can get something like this to work, this could be a nice workaround

Comment: You might look into gnu wget. There is a port available for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Here should be your answer. It is a batch script:

```
start "" chrome "https://google.com;  
Timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F

start "" chrome "https://yahoo.com" 
Timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F

start "" chrome "https://bing.com"
Timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
```